# An error in a simple systemd service

Tags: systemd

I have this systemd service:

$ sudo cat /etc/systemd/system/my_service123.service

```
    [Unit]
    Description=my_service123
    After=syslog.target

    [Service]
    ExecStart=./my_app --config main_cfg.conf
    Restart=on-abort
    WorkingDirectory=/home/user1/my_service_workspace
    SyslogIdentifier=my_service123
    User=user1

    [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I run it:

```
Failed to start my_service123.service: Unit my_service123.service has a bad unit file setting.
See system logs and 'systemctl status my_service123.service' for details.
```

But

```
$ sudo journalctl -u my_service123
No journal files were found.
-- No entries --
```

What's wrong with it?

```
$ sudo systemctl status my_service123
● my_service123.service - ton-node_01
     Loaded: bad-setting (Reason: Unit my_service123.service has a bad unit file setting.)
     Active: inactive (dead)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `systemctl status my_service123.service`. The output will show something like

```
Mar 04 14:39:02 hostname systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/my_service123.service:5: Neither a valid executable name nor an absolute path: <path>
```

Try using an absolute path, then it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Your unit contains this line:

```
ExecStart=./my_app --config main_cfg.conf
```

From the systemd.service man page:

> ExecStart=
> For each of the specified commands, the first argument
> must be either an **absolute path** to an executable or a **simple
> file name without any slashes**.

Comment: that hasn't helped

Comment: Have you tried to specify an absolute path instead of a relative path?